# Proof of boundedness of a function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Let $|x|<1$ and $f(x)=\displaystyle\frac{e^{\frac{1}{1+x}}}{(|x|-1)^{-2}}.$

Is $f(x)$ bounded?

Comment: $f(x)=\displaystyle\frac{e^{\frac{1}{1+x}}}{(|x|-1)^{-2}}$ means $(|x|-1)^{2} e^{\frac{1}{1+x}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that since this function is continuous on $(-1,1)$, we need only check the behavior at the endpoints. On the right we have $f(1)=0$, but at $x=-1$ more work is required.

It may be easier to see what's going on if we make the substitution $u=\frac{1}{x+1}$. Then in the denominator we obtain
$$(|x|-1)^{-2}=(-x-1)^{-2}=(x+1)^{-2}=\left(\frac{1}{x+1}\right)^2=u^2$$
when $-1<x<0$. Therefore we have
$$\lim_{x\to-1^+} f(x)=\lim_{u\to \infty}\frac{e^u}{u^2}$$
which is more straightforward to analyze. L'Hopital's rule, for example, shows that this limit approaches $\infty$. Therefore $f(x)$ is not bounded for $|x|<1$.

Answer (score 0):

$|f(x)| \leq e^{\frac{1}{1+x}}$ because the denominator is smaller than 1.

Only for $x=-1$ you will get $\infty$ for the exponential function, but this value is excluded. Hence $f(x)$ is bounded for $|x| < 1$.

Comment: I think you meant that the denominator is larger than 1. But more importantly, are you saying that $e^{\frac{1}{1+x}}$ is bounded on $(-1,1)$?

Comment: Yes, the exponential function is bounded on $(-1,1)$. Sorry, I have mistaken; Since $|x| \in (-1,1)$, the denominator $(1-|x|)^{-2}$ is greater than $0$, but the Expression $(1-|x|)^2$ (obtained by turning denominator into numerator) is also bounded.

Comment: The exponential function $e^u$ is bounded for $u \in (-1, 1)$. But if $u = \frac{1}{1+x}$ for $x \in (-1, 1)$, then $u \in \left(\frac{1}{2}, \infty\right)$.

Comment: Note that $|x|<1$ is different from $|x| \leq 1$. In your case ($|x| < 1$) the values $x=1$ and $x=-1$ are excluded.

Comment: Let $x = 1 - \ln(1/N)$. Then $e^\frac{1}{1+x} = N$ when $x = \frac{1}{\ln N} - 1$, where $x \in (-1, 1)$ for large enough $N$. ($N > \sqrt{e})$. Hence, $f(x) \geq N$ for some $x \in (-1, 1)$.

Comment: Is $f(x)$ still bounded if $|x|\leq 1.$

Comment: @user35: Contrary to this answer, $f(x)$ is not even bounded for $|x|<1$. But the function is not defined at all when $x=-1$.